# Retire a Dead Windows 2003 Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I have a Windows 2003 Domain Controller that died (totally gone).  We have decided not to replace it at this time (it was just a backup at a particular office).

What do I need to do to remove the domain controller from AD?  It is still listed under 'Sites and Services', and elsewhere I imagine.  It was also a DNS server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need NTDSUTIL.

Here you go: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216498.

Comment: +1 - the article referenced has solved all of my DC removal cases.

Answer (score 1):

As Massimo indicated, you'll need to do a metadata clean-up to get the DC portion of it all out of the picture. You can also go into DNS and make the appropriate change so it's no longer listed as a Name Server (NS).